# could not find function "xgb.DMatrix"

Tags: r, classification, boosting

```
str(new_my_data)
'data.frame':   1082426 obs. of  91 variables:
# ** My all variables are belong to Numerical and integer.

## forming Data set 
train_index <- sample(1:nrow(new_my_data), nrow(new_my_data)*0.75)
data_variables <- as.matrix(new_my_data[,-1])
data_label <- new_my_data[,"has_booking"]
data_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(new_my_data), label = data_label)
```

Getting below error message.

```
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function
> "xgb.DMatrix" Traceback:
```

I am building my model for XGboost (logistic classification).

Comment: You would be better on an R-specific site

Answer (score 1):

maybe try the following?

```
install.packages("xgboost")
library(xgboost)
```

Comment: I installed xgboost. but same issue is happening.